# Multiplying array of vectors by matrix without for loop

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, for-loop, vectorization

I have a `2 x 2` `numpy.array()` `matrix`, and an array `N x 2` `X`, containing `N` 2-dimensional vectors.

I want to multiply each vector in `X` by the `2 x 2` matrix. Below I use a for loop, but I am sure there is a faster way. Please, could someone show me what it is? I assume there is a way using a `numpy` function.

```py
# the matrix I want to multiply X by
matrix = np.array([[0, 1], [-1, 0]]) 

# initialize empty solution
Y = np.empty((N, 2))

# loop over each vector in X and create a new vector Y with the result
for i in range(0, N):
    Y[i] = np.dot(matrix, X[i])
```

For example, these arrays:

```py
matrix = np.array([
    [0,  1],
    [0, -1]
])

X = np.array([
    [0, 0],
    [1, 1],
    [2, 2]
])
```

Should result in:

```py
Y = np.array([
    [0,  0],
    [1, -1],
    [2, -2]
])
```

Comment: "*2-dimensional vectors*" so a matrix? Maybe you mean vectors with 2 items? You should convert X to an array so to perform a matrix multiplication. If the vector do not have the same length, then the loop is mandatory with Numpy (because you cannot create a ND array and lists require loops or equivalent slow operations like map).

Comment: Isn't it just a matter of `Y = matrix * X`? Can you post a sample `X` and the expected `Y` result?

Comment: you have a (2,2) matrix and a (2,) X[i] . np.dot will do the sum and multiplication (each line of matrix is multiplied by X[i] element wide, then sum is done on line). Is this what you want ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One-liner is `(matrix @ X.T).T`

Just transpose your X, to get your vectors in columns. Then `matrix @ X.T` or (`np.dot(matrix, X.T)` if you prefer this solution, but now that `@` notation exists, why not using it) is a matrix made of columns of matrix times `X[i]`. Just transpose back the result if you need Y to be made of lines of results

```py
matrix = np.array([[0, 1], [-1, 0]]) 
X = np.array([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]])
Y = (matrix @ X.T).T
```

Y is

```
array([[ 2, -1],
       [ 4, -3],
       [ 6, -5]])
```

As expected, I guess.

In detail:
`X` is

```
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4],
       [5, 6]])
```

so `X.T` is

```
array([[1, 3, 5],
       [2, 4, 6]])
```

So, you can multiply your 2x2 matrix by this 2x3 matrix, and the result will be a 2x3 matrix whose columns are the result of multiplication of `matrix` by the column of this. `matrix @ X.T` is

```
array([[ 2,  4,  6],
       [-1, -3, -5]])
```

And transposing back this gives the already given result.

So, tl;dr: one-liner answer is `(matrix @ X.T).T`

Comment: Ok thanks, so I can just use @ instead of np.dot. I never knew.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing some kind of matrix multiplication with (2,2) matrix and each (2,1) X line.
You need to make all your vectors the same dimension to directly calculate this. Add a dimension with None and directly calculate Y like this :

```
matrix = np.array([[3, 1], [-1, 0.1]]) 
N = 10
Y = np.empty((N, 2))
X =np.ones((N,2))
X[0][0] = 2
X[5][1] = 3
# loop over each vector in X and create a new vector Y with the result
for i in range(0, N):
    Y[i] = np.dot(matrix, X[i])

Ydirect = matrix[None,:] @ X[:,:,None]
print(Y)
print(Ydirect[:,:,0])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can vectorize Adrien's result and remove the for loop, which will optimize performance, especially as the matrices get bigger.

```
matrix = np.array([[3, 1], [-1, 0.1]])

N = 10

X = np.ones((N, 2))
X[0][0] = 2
X[5][1] = 3

# calculate dot product using @ operator
Y = matrix @ X.T


print(Y)
```